# In SHAP force plot, is there a way to change the value of x-axis to custom name?

Tags: python, shap, lime

In the SHAP force plot, is there a way to change the value of the x-axis to a custom name?

```
f = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
shap.summary_plot(shap_values, X_test, plot_type="bar", feature_names=X_train.columns, class_names = ORGD_Test['Class'])
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Are you interested in `force_plot` or `summary_plot`? It's not clear from your question, please clarify.

Comment: Hi did you find an answer to this? I'm also looking to change the x-axis in the shap force plot - from the row indices to names I've given each row

Answer (score 0):

```
shap.summary_plot(shap_values, show=False)

# Get the current figure and axes objects.
fig, ax = plt.gcf(), plt.gca()

# Set the limits for the x-axis and similarly can be done for the y-axis also
ax.set_xlim(-60, 125)
ax.set_xlim(-60, 125)
ax.set_title(ax_title, fontdict={"size":font_size})
```